# How to retrieve data without using database,it has to display in listview

Tags: java, android

I am creating one dynamic list view i don't need database to store the data,whatever i am adding the data,it has to display in my list view. Right now its not displaying in my list view.
Projectlistactivity.java

```
public class Prayers extends ListActivity{
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;

    /** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    /** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prayers_list);

        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        //btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

        /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
        setListAdapter(adapter);



    }

    private void fillData() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_insert: 
            createProject();
            return true; 

        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
    private void createProject() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PrayersEditActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);   
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_prayers_list, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

This is my projecteditactivity.java

```
public class PrayersEditActivity extends Activity{
    private EditText mTitleText;
     private Button mConfirmButton;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_prayers_edit);

             mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
             mConfirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);



             registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();    
     }
     private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {
         mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //saveState(); 

                    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
                    mTitleText.setText("");

                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    Toast.makeText(PrayersEditActivity.this, getString(R.string.task_saved_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish(); 
                }

            });
     }
         /*private void saveState() {
             //mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
             String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();

             mTitleText.setText("");
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }*/



}
```

In my listview if i click the menu button it has to go to the edit page,in their i have to add project after clicking the save button,it has to display in my listview,Right now its not display in my listview.

Answer (score 2):

startActivityForResult(i, 1); and override this method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) {

     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
         String result=data.getStringExtra("result"); 
         list.add(result);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
     if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //Write your code if there's no result
     }
   }
 }
```

in your projecteditactivity.java change the onClick to following code

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
                mTitleText.setText("");                   


                 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                 returnIntent.putExtra("result",title);
                 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);    

                finish(); 
            }
```

Comment: its not displaying in listview

Comment: did you change  startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE); to startActivityForResult(i, 1);

Comment: Dude,Now whats happening here is,first time running na,that time what i am adding is showing for all moment,if i add next time ,that data is not showing,only the first time adding data is showing

Comment: you mean to say is it that once you close the application and open again you will not have the data. in that case yes because once the activity is destroyed the data is lost.

Comment: ya and one more thing,whatever i am adding first in the listview,its only showing not the next adding,its showing only the first data what i am adding,next data if i add its not displaying in listview

Comment: i checked its working fine. check whether you have missed this list.add(result); this should be before adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  and remove this setContentView(R.layout.activity_prayers_list); from your players class

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you store the data in a file, so that, you can retrive it when the application goes to background and after a few time, when come back, you can retrive it from file if memory lost happend. 
I used to keep data in a Json formatted string, Dont know how and from where you get the list data.

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-items-to-listview-in-android/ can you look at these link here also they didnt save.like that i want to do right now.whatever i am creating it has to display

Answer (score 0):

you may use the life_cycle function. In addtion, you may transmit the data between Activities. So that you can use the edit data to display.

Comment: could you tell,how to do in my activity?

Answer (score 0):

keep your data with ondestroy, onpause and onresume method.. and second option is to keep it with sharedprefence or sqlite.